# How can you draw a circle point by point, moving sequentially along the circumference?

Tags: php, algorithm, math

Please tell me how I can build a circle point by point, making sure to move sequentially around the circle like the hand of a clock.

Now I can build a circle, but in my loop the points are placed in a random order and at the end I get a circle.

```
theta = 0, x = 16, y = 6
theta = 1, x = 11, y = 14
theta = 2, x = 2, y = 15
theta = 3, x = -4, y = 7
theta = 4, x = -1, y = -2
theta = 5, x = 9, y = -4
```

I need to build a circle sequentially, so that for example I can draw only half a circle or draw a circle with certain changing colors. I assume it's all in radians, but we need to use degrees somehow. But I have no more ideas. Thanks.

```
$radius = 10;
$centerX = 6;
$centerY = 6;

$theta = 0;

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 0);

while ($theta <= 360) {
    $x = round($centerX + $radius * cos($theta));
    $y = round($centerY + $radius * sin($theta));
    $theta += 1;

    imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $white);
}
```

I tried to use the deg2rad() function to somehow use degrees, but my knowledge of mathematics is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use the deg2rad() function to somehow use degrees"

You were close. Both [cos()](https://php.net/cos) and [sin()](https://php.net/sin) expect radians so that part should have been right. Alternatively, you can work directly in radians. Rather than looping from 0 to 360, loop from 0 to `2 * M_PI` and make your increments smaller (e.g. `M_PI / 100`).

Additionally:

- [imagecolorallocate()](https://php.net/imagecolorallocate) component order is RGB, so your `$white` was actually electric green.
- Not a problem, but `for` is a bit more compact (readable?) that `while` for this use case.

All together, with some polishing:

```
$radius = 150;
$step = M_PI / 100;
$centerX = $centerY = $radius;

$im = imagecreate(2 * $radius, 2 * $radius);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

for ($theta = 0; $theta < 2 * M_PI; $theta += $step) {
    $x = round($centerX + $radius * cos($theta));
    $y = round($centerY + $radius * sin($theta));
    imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $white);
}

imagepng($im, '/tmp/circle.png');
```

Output:

[image: Rendered circl]

Degrees version:

```
$radius = 150;
$step = 1;
$centerX = $centerY = $radius;

$im = imagecreate(2 * $radius, 2 * $radius);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

for ($theta = 0; $theta < 360; $theta += $step) {
    $x = round($centerX + $radius * cos(deg2rad($theta)));
    $y = round($centerY + $radius * sin(deg2rad($theta)));
    imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $white);
}

imagepng($im, '/tmp/circle.png');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it so thoroughly. The most important thing in my problem was the not use of M_PI

Comment: @VincentRandall Do you have any other doubt? Is something unclear or not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Midpoint (Bresenham's) circle drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for its efficiency. These computer graphics algorithms are used to quickly draw graphics primitives such as a circle.

I implemented a JavaScript version sometime ago; you might want to look into that: https://ratcoinc.github.io/GFX/circle.html

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it almost correctly, you just need to use the `imagecreate()` function to create an image, and after the `while` loop use `imagepng()` to render the image, and don't forget to use add a proper `Content-Type` header to render the image correctly in the browser.

Here's the modified code, I've made some changes:

```
header('Content-type: image/png'); 

$im = imagecreate(500, 500);

$radius = 100;
$centerX = 250;
$centerY = 250;

$theta = 0;

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 0); // use a background color for the image
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); // use a black color for the line

while ($theta <= 360) {
    $x = round($centerX + $radius * cos($theta));
    $y = round($centerY + $radius * sin($theta));
    $theta += 1;

    imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $black); // draw the perimeter as dots
}

imagepng($im); // send the image to the browser
```

You were using a line color that's identical to the background color, so you wouldn't have been able to see the circle. Here, I've used a different color.

Here's an image of the result:

[image]

**Note:** you could make `$theta` increase by smaller values (e.g. 0.5, 0.2, 0.1) to get a smoother look.

Comment: It's hard to spot because there are many of them, but points are not evenly distributed. That's because you're working with degrees (where 360º is the full circle) but PHP trigonometry functions work with radians (where full circle is 2×π ≈ 6.28).